# $v ∈ V$ is an Eigen vector of $T$ corr. to the Eigen value $c$$\iff$ $[v]_B$ is an Eigen vector of $[T]_B$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Justify:**

> Choose a basis $B$ of $V.$ Then $v ∈ V$ is an Eigen vector of $T$ corr. to the Eigen value $c$$\iff$ $[v]_B$ is an Eigen vector of $[T]_B$ cor. to eigenvalue $c$. $([v]_B$ being the coordinate matrix of $v$ w.r.t. $B$ and $[T]_B$ is the matrix representation of w.r.t. $B)$

Please help me. I'm clueless!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a basis $B=(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)$ of $V$ such that 
$$T(e_1,e_2,...e_n)=(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)[T]_B$$
$$v=(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)[v]_B$$
So $$Tv=(e_1,e_2,...e_n)[T]_B[v]_B$$
While $$cv=(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)c[v]_B$$
From $Tv=cv$,we get 
$$(e_1,e_2,...e_n)[T]_B[v]_B=(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)c[v]_B$$
If we write the above equation with the form of  $\sum_{i=0}^na_ie_i=0$ ,  due to the linear independence of $e_i$, we have coefficient $a_i=0$, i.e.
$$[T]_B[v]_B=c[v]_B$$

Conversely, from $[T]_B[v]_B=c[v]_B$, we can also see $Tv=cv$.
Thus,we proof this equivalence.